# Git - Overview of differences between branches

Tags: git, tfs

What's the best way to accomplish the following:

Sprint is done, code of 4 out of 14 applications has been updated and now has to be merged from Dev to pre-release.

But do we forget anything? Do you remember what we did at the beginning of this sprint? Maybe this application?

We should have a webpage where we can see which commits in dev, in what repo, are not yet merged from Dev to pre-release. Even if it's as basic as "this repo has been changed in the past 2 weeks".

Comment: try  reading this article https://www.atlassian.com/agile/software-development/git

Comment: Hi @PatrickLu-MSFT,
No... We haven't had time for the implementation, even though we really need it. Anyway. I think your answer will help me a great deal, so it's only fair to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see which commits in dev, in what repo, are not yet merged from Dev to pre-release, you could do this in local git repo through graph instead of web port of TFS.

> 1. Locate the object in the Solution Explorer, and bring up the context menu (right-click): select "**View History...**". This brings
>      up the History window for this object, with all the commits ***where
>      the object changed*** (from any branch).
> 2. Multi-select the two commits that you want to compare (left-click on the first one, Ctrl-left-click on the second one).
> 3. Now bring up the context menu on either of the selected commits (right_click): select "Compare...". This brings up the Diff window for
>      the object in the respective commits (with the differences highlighted
>      in red -lines removed from first commit- or green -lines added in
>      second commit). You can use the scroll bar in the Diff window, or the
>      "Previous Difference" and "Next Difference" button in the ribbon to go
>      between the differences of the object.

---

On TFS web portal, when you right click on a branch under Code->Branches, you will get this menu. Click on compare branches.

[image]

Another way is

1. Go to Code -> Branches
2. Click on the commit diff count to the right of the updated date as in this screenshot:
   [image: vsts_screenshot]

This will take you to a page that shows both a commit difference between the two, and a file comparison